# In view row data value can be shown in seperate column when we use group by

Tags: sql-server

My SQL code is this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[UDV_Project_Summary_With_Beneficiary]
    SELECT 
        FiscalYear.FiscalYearName AS [Fiscal Year],
        dbo.Region.RegionName AS Region,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(Project.ProjectID)) AS [No of Projects],
        SUM(ISNULL(Project.Amount, 0) + ISNULL(Project.ContAmount, 0)) AS Amount,
        [dbo].[UDF_Get_BName](1, [dbo].[ProjectBeneficiaryDetail].BeneficiaryTypeID) AS Beneficiaries,
        SUM(ISNULL(ActualNoOfMale, 0)) AS Men,
        SUM(ISNULL(ActualNoOfFemale, 0)) AS Women,
        SUM(ISNULL(ActualNoOfMale, 0) + ISNULL(ActualNoOfFemale, 0)) AS Total
    FROM             
        dbo.Project 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Commune ON dbo.Project.CommuneIdProject = dbo.Commune.CommuneId 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Arrondissement ON dbo.Arrondissement.[ArrondissementId] = dbo.Commune.[ArrondissementId] 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Cercle ON dbo.Cercle.CercleId = dbo.Arrondissement.CercleId 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Region ON dbo.Region.RegionId = dbo.Cercle.RegionId 
    INNER JOIN
        ImplementingPartner ON dbo.ImplementingPartner.IPID = dbo.Project.IPID  
    INNER JOIN
        FiscalYear ON dbo.Project.FiscalYearID = dbo.FiscalYear.FiscalYearID 
    INNER JOIN
        ProjectCategory ON dbo.Project.ProjectCategoryID = dbo.ProjectCategory.ProjectCategoryID 
    INNER JOIN
        ProjectStatus ON dbo.Project.ProjectStatusID = dbo.ProjectStatus.ProjectStatusID 
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[ImplementingPartnerType] ON [dbo].[ImplementingPartnerType].[ImplementingPartnerTypeID] = ImplementingPartner.[ImplementingPartnerTypeID] 
    LEFT JOIN
        [dbo].[ProjectBeneficiaryDetail] ON dbo.Project.ProjectID =  dbo.[ProjectBeneficiaryDetail].ProjectID 
    GROUP BY  
        FiscalYear.FiscalYearName, Region.RegionName, [dbo].[ProjectBeneficiaryDetail].BeneficiaryTypeID
```

The result is shown in this screenshot:

[image]

But I want to display like below image data using SQL code. Please help me how it can be done

I am trying to do it by using PIVOT but not success.I try like this
step 1 i have inserted value in Beneficiary_ProjectType_Template from view

select [Intervention Areas], [No of Projects], Amount, Beneficiaries, Men, Women, Total 
into Beneficiary_ProjectType_Template
from [dbo].[UDV_Project_Summary_With_Beneficiary_ProjectType]

step 2 Below SQL

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(dbo.Beneficiary_ProjectType_Template.[No of Projects]) 
                    from Beneficiary_ProjectType_Template
                    group by Beneficiary_ProjectType_Template.[No of Projects]
                    order by Beneficiary_ProjectType_Template.[No of Projects]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [Intervention Areas]  ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select [Intervention Areas], [No of Projects], Amount, Beneficiaries
                from Beneficiary_ProjectType_Template
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(Amount)
                for Beneficiaries in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
Help me how pivot can be use proper way to get result as below image.
With many thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this in SQL? This should be pretty easy to do in most reporting tools. Otherwise look into the PIVOT keyword.

Comment: To use crystal report graph on different dimension,currently gives not actual value